# footer and header don't fill width 100 % when restoring down the browser window

Tags: css, width, footer

I have a website that when viewing in mozilla, Ie, chrome and safari on the full maximized window achieves the 100% width in the footer and header image, but when restoring down (resizing the window) a scrollbar appears, obviously because the footer has 4 sections that are fixed widths but the background image don't fill the 100% width?  I can't figure out what it is.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/mveq4/

```
    /*footer*/
    div#footerwrap {
        width:100%;
        height:5px;
        clear:both;
        background:url(images/footerred.png)repeat-x;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    div#footerwrap2 {
        width:100%;
        height:550px;
        clear:both;
        background-color:#222222;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        padding-bottom:0.3em;
    }
    div#footer {
        font: 9pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        clear:both;
        padding:0em;
        color:#fff;
        height:550px;
        margin:0px auto;
        width:1000px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    div#footer a {
        color:#d41919;
    }
    div#footer a:hover {
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#footer a:visited {
        color:#d41919;
    }
    div#firstfooter {
        margin:0;
        float:left;
        height:370px;
        padding:0em;
        padding-top:0.9em;
        width:220px;
        font: bold 10pt Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        text-align:left;
        color:#d41919;
    }
    div#firstfooter a {
        color:#d41919;
    }
    div#footernav {
        margin:0em;
        padding:0em;
        padding-top:1em;
        font: 11pt Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        float:left;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:left;
        color:#d41919;
        width:200px;
        list-style:none;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    div#footernav a {
        color:#d41919;
    }
    div#footernav a:hover {
        color:#fff;
    }
    ul.footermenu {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        font-size:9pt;
        font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        color:#d41919;
    }
    ul.footermenu>li {
        list-style:none;
        color:#d41919;
    }
    ul.footermenu li a {
        padding:0.5em;
        padding-bottom:0.30em;
        padding-top:0.40em;
        text-decoration: none;
        outline:none;
        line-height:2.5em;
        color:#d41919;
    }
    ul.footermenu li a:link {
        color:#d41919;
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul.footermenu li a:visited {
        color:#d41919;
    }
    ul.footermenu li a:hover {
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#secondfooter {
        margin:0;
        float:left;
        height:370px;
        padding:0em;
        padding-top:1em;
        width:250px;
        font: bold 9pt Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        text-align:left;
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#secondfooter a {
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#secondfooter a:hover {
        color:#fff;
    }
    textarea {
        overflow:auto;
    }
    /*contact*/
    #fieldset {
        width:250px;
        height:250px;
        padding:1em;
        padding-left:0em;
        margin:0;
        border:none;
        text-align:justify;
        float:left;
    }
    input {
        color: #fff;
        background: #333;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        padding:0.8em;
    }
    .submitinput {
        color: #d41919;
        background: #333;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        cursor:pointer;
        padding:0.2em;
        text-align:center;
    }
    textarea {
        color: #fff;
        background: #333;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        padding:0.2em;
    }
    div#thirdfooter {
        margin:0;
        float:left;
        height:500px;
        padding:0em;
        padding-top:1em;
        width:250px;
        font: bold 9pt Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        text-align:left;
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#thirdfooter a {
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#thirdfooter a:hover {
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#rightfooter {
        margin:0em;
        margin-left:750px;
        padding:0em;
        padding-top:1em;
        height:500px;
        width:250px;
        font: 9pt Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        color:#fff;
        text-align:left;
    }
    div#rightfooter a {
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#rightfooter a:hover {
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#footerbottom {
        clear:both;
        background-color:#d41919;
        height:60px;
        width:100%;
        color:#fff;
        font: 8pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding:0em;
        padding-top:0.5em;
        margin:0px auto;
        text-align:center;
    }
    div#footerbottom a {
        text-decoration:none;
        outline:none;
        color:#fff;
    }
    div#footerbottom a:hover {
        color:#000;
    }
```

Comment: Code please or better yet, a JSFiddle

Comment: Your question i have to say is poorly worded, and i find it hard to understand what your problem is? But from what i can guess the background isn't persistently staying black when expanding the page width-wise then scrolling right?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your body part of your CSS file.

**CSS**

```
body {

    background-color:#000; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"width: 100%" means, it will take full width of the parent element. In your case, body element is the parent of #footerwrap. Remember that, if you do not define an exact width in px or such parameters (not in %) in body, its width will be the visible width of the browser.

body width = #footerwrap width = visible width

So when you reduce the window width, width of #footerwrap also decreases.

To solve your problem, you should use a min-width for #footerwrap.

```
div#footerwrap,
div#footerwrap2 {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px; /* Equal to the inner element's width */
}
```